# extracts a given number of characters from the left side of string paramater

Tags: pandas

I have an ID paramater in pandas df .

df['id']

I want to keep only the 4 first characters from the left side(like left function in excel).

for example

54354832 > 5435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df["ID"]=df.loc[:,"ID"].str[0:4]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["abcdefg", "abcdefg", "abcdefg"], "b": ["abcdefg", "abcdefg", "abcdefg"]})
df["ID"]=df.loc[:,"ID"].str[0:4]
```